# Convention for Separating Admin Controls

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

My question concerns the convention for using two different Controllers to influence the same Model.

I have a catalogue section of this website, and generally speaking, it's controlled by, appropriately enough, the Catalogue Controller. However, I'm also coding the Administrative functionality of adding, editing, or removing entries in the catalogue. Generally speaking, Admin functionality is being handled by the Admin Controller.

If I'm trying to give admins the ability to edit the catalogue, would the proper or accepted convention be to add that functionality to the Catalogue controller, or to the Admin controller? Is it even advisable to have a separate Admin controller? Obviously both methods would work, and there may not even BE an accepted convention, but I wanted to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is: if I'm trying to give admins the ability to edit
>   the catalogue, would the proper or accepted convention be to add that
>   functionality to the Catalogue controller, or to the Admin controller?
>   Is it even advisable to have a separate Admin controller?

Admin functions should ALWAYS be in separate controllers. NEVER mix admin tools with controllers that are serving a public website.

in the constructor of your Admin Controllers -- you will check to make sure that its a verified Admin - or you bounce them out of there. In other words they don't get into the controller at all, and then you aren't having to check for a valid admin in all your methods.

Admin view files should always be separate from the website view files, and again because you have checked for valid login, you don't have to check in the view files.

your Admin Catalog controller can pull data from the same model that the website uses. And technically you could put admin methods in there as well. but i would strongly urge you keep them separate. in other words you are going to have models that have admin tools and those models are only accessed by Admin controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke a Catalog_model which handles the functionality for editing stuff. This model than gets called by the controller that needs the model.

Comment: I know that. But which CONTROLLER should be used, Admin or Catalogue? Is there a conventional answer?

Comment: The catalogue controller should handle catalogue stuff. But when using CodeIgniter, well, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: So conventionally, I should avoid a separate Admin controller?

Comment: When you have administrative tasks which should be handled with a separate controller, than you can use an admin controller. In any case, you should ask yourself what makes most sense to you and what feels best

Comment: See, this is where it's all wishy-washy. 'That should be handled with a separate controller'. How do you make that determination? How does one know which tasks should be handled with a separate controller, and which should not? Realistically, isn't EVERY administrative task on a website part of a larger area, like editing a catalogue would be part of the catalogue controller, editing users would be part of the user controller, etc.

Comment: As i said before, do what makes most sense for you :-)

Comment: You're looking to apply rule based logic here like you do in programming - this rule set determines this controller. Nope! You learn through every experience, other code bases etc, eventually you'll know which one 'feels' right.